# How to Convert Quadratic Contraint to Linear

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

I have this constraint in my model:

```
(X - Y) @ B >= 0
```

where B is a boolean vector variable, X and Y are variables vector that represent quantities

I'm working with CVXPY, so I have to keep linear expressions

How could I translate this constraint in a way that is linear?

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `X>=0` and `Y>=0`. In that case, we can somewhat easily linearize `XB=X*B` and `YB=Y*B`.

```
   XB <= X
   XB <= B*999
   XB >= X-999*(1-B)
   0 <= XB <= 999
```

Here 999 is an upper bound on `X`. Similar for `YB`. Now just add:

```
   XB >= YB
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time!, one question, I should add the same constraints for YB too?, YB <= Y, YB <= B*999, etc?

Comment: Yes, "*Similar for YB*"